# React.js component apparently renders, but no change in what's displayed

Tags: reactjs

This is my first venture into React territory, so I'm sure my problem is a simple newbie one. As an exercise I'm trying to convert an existing working web application to use React. I have a ProductTable which displays a list of products. It has a 'selectedProducts' field as part of its state, which gets updated whenever the product selection changes. My assumption was that changing this value (state) should cause a re-rendering with any new selection.

On first display, the component displays successfully and correctly shows the list of products. However, when a change is made to the selection, what is displayed on screen does not change. Yet from console logging and use of React tools in Chrome, I can see that the 'selectedProducts' field state has indeed changed, and in fact a console log entry in the render method shows that render for the component is in fact being called, with the new selection. But it's not changing what's displayed on screen - the table continues to show the old selection of products - and I really can't figure that out.

Any suggestions as to where to look? I appreciate it might be clearer with some code here but it's slightly difficult to present it in a concise way given that it's a conversion of an existing web application, so I hope my description above is sufficient to suggest something to the experts here.

EDIT: Code of component added here. As you will see, notification is done by means of pub/sub. I've stuck with the global 'productSelection' object for now, but that would be refactored in due course. At the moment the idea is that some other code makes changes to that global variable and then notifies the ProductTable component via pub/sub. As I mentioned, the notification is working fine, the 'selectedProducts' variable is clearly being changed and render is being run - but no visible change is occurring.

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            selectedProducts: [],
         };
    },


    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.pubsubToken = Arbiter.subscribe('products/selection', function() {
            // update my selection when there is a message
            console.log("Setting selection to "+productSelection.length);
            this.setState({ selectedProducts: productSelection });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentWillUnmount:function(){
        Arbiter.unsubscribe(this.pubsubToken);
    },


    render: function () {

        var rows = this.state.selectedProducts.map(function (product, i) {
            return <ProductRow key={product.code} product={product}/>;
        });
        console.log("Running render for ProductTable with "+rows.length+" rows");

        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="products" id="productsLabel">Available products (click or double-click to select):</label>
                <table id="products" className="st-container">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td className="st-head" style={{padding:"0px 18px 0px 0px"}}>
                            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0" className="st-head-table" style={{width: "100%"}}>
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th className="rem" colSpan="0"></th>
                                    <th className="code" colSpan="0">Code</th>
                                    <th className="name" colSpan="0">Name</th>
                                    <th className="pack" colSpan="0">Pack</th>
                                    <th className="size" colSpan="0">Size</th>
                                    <th className="attribs" colSpan="0"></th>
                                    <th className="price" colSpan="0">Price</th>
                                    <th className="unit" colSpan="0">Unit</th>
                                    <th className="rrp" colSpan="0">RRP</th>
                                    <th className="vat" colSpan="0">VAT</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td className="st-body" style={{padding:"0px"}}>
                            <div className="st-body-scroll" style={{overflowY: "scroll", maxHeight: "250px"}}>
                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0" className="st-body-table" style={{width: "100%"}}>
                                    <tbody id="productRows">
                                    ${rows}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably something with the state of you component but please show some code , hard to help without that, at least the code of you component

Comment: Here's the component itself:

Comment: where ? =p hmm ? use ctrl + k to display your code

Comment: In the original post - sorry, screwed up with the comment.

Comment: have you tried my solution ? is it working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see, you need to use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount because, as stated in the doc : *If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.*

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount

Use componentDidMount and everything should be fine.

**Edit:**
you don't need ${rows} but just {rows}. Also I would suggest you check your new data, are they really different form the initial one ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which looked very promising, but unfortunately it makes no difference - the behaviour is identical. That is, I see in my console log messages like 'Setting selection to 15' and then 'Running render for ProductTable with 15 rows', but what I see on screen is still the original table, unchanged.

Comment: Well spotted! The leading $ was a relic of the existing version (server-side build), and I hadn't noticed it was still there. Removing it has cleared the problem and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat disappointingly, now I have it working, I find that, in its current form at least, my React solution is considerably slower than the existing system - which is obviously not what I was hoping for! The table displays a maximum of around 4000 rows (in a fixed size 'window'), which is just on the border of unwieldiness for a browser. The existing solution goes through the products array and simply builds a table by string concatenation, outputting the finished item to a div. This seems to be faster than React's shenanigans with the virtual DOM, at least for large numbers of rows.

Comment: 4000 rows ? isn't it a terrible bad practice  ? why not using pagination ?

Comment: It works fast enough in the existing system, and far more smoothly than pagination. As I said, 4000 is on the edge - more than that and I think it would start to cause problems. I know there are data grid solutions out there successfully displaying a million records using infinite scrolling, so it can be done.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I mean: http://w2ui.com/web/blog/7/JavaScript-Grid-with-One-Million-Records

Comment: I guess the limit is the weight of your page, 5mb should be a max, how can you have 1M lines in less than 5mb ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89835/discussion-between-john-moore-and-francois-richard).